# Is there a way map a closed interval to the real line?

Tags: functions

Is it possible to map an interval $[a,b]$ onto $\mathbb R$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$?

EDIT: Is there a way to make the mapping continuous? In other words, to obtain a continuous function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes; it can even be done bijectively, since they have the same cardinality.

Comment: I take it you mean map *onto* $\mathbb R$. Just extend $\tan$ to $\left[-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right]$ as you wish.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you for pointing that out. It is corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do it continuously, because $\Bbb R$ has no endpoints.  But you can make a bijection.  One way is to biject $[a,b]$ with $(a,b)$, then to biject $(a,b)$ with $\Bbb R$. For the first, just take $a$ into the interval in a convenient way, move the point you just landed on somewhere else, and continue.  Do the same starting with $b$

It cannot be continuous because a continuous function on a closed interval attains its maximum and minimum.  Therefore you will miss some of (almost all of) $\Bbb R$ in the image.